# Low cost position detection using a diy "encoder"

Tags: encoder, diy, optical

I'm building a machine that is adjustable, so there is this mechanical arm that can be in 5 different positions. I was thinking on building a custom encoder, I can easily make holes in each position so that they are detected by 3 optical reflective sensors, each different combination of holes will be read by a PLC (24V power supply). But all I can find are very expensive optical reflective sensors above $30 and that's out of budget. Pretty sure there are inexpensive solutions out there, can anyone give me some pointers in the good direction please?

EDIT:
a quick diagram to explain better, the moving part will be positioned in the small cut so no precision issues, I just want to detect in each of the 5 positions it is, but using the smallest number of IOs possible.

[image]

Comment: A bit hard to imagine what you are doing, and what level of alignment precision you need, but can you attach a potentiometer to the arm ? Then just read the resistance

Comment: Or for 24V PLC systems, use a [proximity sensor](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=plc+proximity+sensor&t=opera&iax=images&ia=images).

Comment: If you have LEDs , they can also be used as photodiodes in reverse 5V max into a large R value ~100k to create a voltage from a small current,. Heat shrink over 5mm can block stray light. Then compare with some Vref for about $1

Comment: You can even use CMOS logic gates as a voltage comparator.with 5V near Vcc/2 and this may be precise enough. But through hole detection is optically easier and more reliable than reflective which must be very close <5mm and both be recessed with optical shrouds for a narrow IR beam.   you can also buy, but you need a good black non reflective surface. (Black sharpy ink)

Comment: https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/result?s=N4IgTCBcDaIPIAcAuBLAxgQwDYAIDOApgHZ4D2ATiALoC%2BQA

Comment: How are speed and position controlled? How big?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 the displacement is manual and the arm is about 1 meter long.

Comment: Can you use transmissive with 1 LED on 1 side going to X of 3 holes to 3x 5mm PDs with heat shrink aimed through holes to LEDfastened with hot glue going to Cat 4/5 wire or with DIP IC to decode locally to logic level out? Minimum 5 wires for entire cct.

Comment: You could also use Hall effect sensors to detect the presence of small magnets.

Comment: You could use 1 hole per position but 5 different offsets from edge

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Using 1 hole per position with serial shared LED current and PD's (photodiodes or even LEDs in reverse but -5V only.)

- Use 20mA for all LEDs
- insert LED's in 5mm holes and black heatshrink over 5mm PD's aimed at hole within 5mm gap.

Comment: Conflicts? Comments?

Answer (score 0):

[image: reflective optical coupler]

You should be able to find simple **reflective optical couplers** containing an infra-red light-emitting diode, alongside a phototransistor sensor for under $1.

The passive reflective surface is something you'd add to the movable item. In this particular sensor, optimum distance between reflective surface, and optical devices is about 1mm for the device shown. You can shape this reflective surface to accommodate position precision.
You might use five of these sensors: one at each of five positions on the 1m fixed bed.

The phototransistor creates a current somewhat proportional to reflected light. For versatility, it is good to sense this variable current to determine if the reflective surface is present or not.
Since both infra-red light emitter, and phototransistor respond quickly, it is possible to use some intelligence to improve reliability:

For example, the phototransistor senses *ambient light* as well as light created by the light-emitting-diode, making it difficult to sense when the reflecting surface is present - or not.
Ambient light can be rejected by turning the LED on, making a phototransistor current measurement (I1), then turning the LED off, and making another phototransistor current measurement (I2). The difference between these two measurements (I1-I2) rejects ambient light, which is present for **both** measurements. Thus the reliability of detecting whether the reflector is present (or not) is improved.

---

Using these optical couplers to create a digital signal directly is also possible, but choosing a light threshold where it switches might be less-reliable due to ambient light, or variations from device to device.
This is the usual, simple and straightforward method used.